# Detect ie10, < ie10 and other browsers in php

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I have this code to detect if user is using IE Browser, however I would like to detect if it is ie 10 or a version below ie 10

```
<?php
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent)){
       //do something
       //HOW TO KNOW IS IE 10
       // HOW TO KNOW BROWSER VERSION IS LESS THAN IE 10?
    }else{
       //hope users would always use other browser than IE 
    } 

    ?>
```

so is it correct?

```
 <?php
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        //IE
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent)){

           //IE 10
           if(preg_match('/msie 10/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                     //  DO IE10.
           // < IE 10
           }else{
                     //  DO < IE10.
           } 

        }else{
           //OTHER BROWSERS 
           //hope users would always use other browser than IE 
        } 

        ?>
```

Comment: Thats a pretty simple regex, you probably don't need it and you can just use `stripos( $u_agent, 'MSIE') !== false`.

Comment: Ok, but how to know if is ie 10 ? using `strcmp("MSIE 10", $var)`? or something

Comment: Just a friendly comment here. First I hope you are not one of these people serving up a blank page cause it is IE or some extremely crippled page. That aside, it is not a 'best practice' to detect browser and version anymore. You should detect features and act accordingly. Libraries like modernizr are great for this.

Comment: to answer your comment is the same as I once red in a SO question, It is the case of an old application developed exclusevely to IE6-I7, now as time goes, other browsers act really well, except for particularities of IE, even IE10, so thats why, We currently do not have the time to sit down and verify each feature.Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might help you:

```
<?php 
//echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

 if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [10]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // if IE = 10
   echo "version is IE 10"; //rest of your code
}
else
{
    // if not 10
     echo "version is not 10"; //rest of your code
}
 ?>
```

[Demo Here>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rSaMD2)

**Edit:**
Break into 3 cases:

```
<?php 
//echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

 if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-9]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // if IE <= 10
   echo "version is less than 10"; //rest of your code
} else  if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [10]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // if IE = 10
   echo "version is IE 10"; //rest of your code
}
else
{
    // if not 10
     echo " other browser"; //rest of your code

}
 ?>
```

[Demo Here>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NoF2fQ)

Comment: useful, but  how  to split all 3 cases? IE10, <IE10, other

Comment: @cMinor You can use the Trident check - see my answer next down. I've been using it to detect anything IE and not Edge but you can also use it to find IE versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily check for IE in the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` server variable.

```
if(preg_match('/msie [2-10]/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    // This user is using IE2 - IE10.
} else {
    // Using something else.
}
```

---

If you want to **specifically** target IE10, you can use:

```
if(preg_match('/msie 10/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    // This user is using IE10.
} else {
    // Using something else.
}
```

Comment: I would like to split it in 3  cases ie 10, < ie 10 and other browsers... so after `else{ if{ IE10  }else{}  }`

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer with your solution. Should be simple enough to mix up my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check on for the Trident string:

```
Trident/4* = Internet Explorer 8
Trident/5* = Internet Explorer 9
Trident/6* = Internet Explorer 10
Trident/7* = Internet Explorer 11
Edge/* = Edge
```

So for SVG animation checking I can do:

```
$IE = preg_match('/Trident\//i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

All the references you need are here:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537503(v=vs.85)